# Tomcat running on 8080 port but Fails to redirect to 8443 HTTPS port .. The 8443 port is running but cant access in web

Tags: https, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat8, sysadmin

I have deployed webapps with apache-tomcat-8.5.37. It had ssl and was working fine but when I tried to renew the ssl and installed JKS file it started to show different problems. I have resolved various cases but could not resolve the port redirection problem. The port is listed in `netstat` but doesn't work in web where my grails app is running.

I have attached my logs [here](https://pastebin.com/JnHhqe6v)

And [HERE](https://pastebin.com/sd03eaQm) is my server.xml configuration file.

[image: Netstat picture]

Comment: How did you configure the (`HTTP`) redirection between port `8080` and port `8443`? Did you add a `<security-constraint>` to your deployment descriptor (`web.xml`)? From the screenshot I notice that your server has a private IP (`172.31.9.103`). Is there a (`DNAT`) port redirection from a public address?

Comment: Thankyou @Piort for your concern ... everything was all right .. http Nio was in place ... port was closed actually from aws ... sorted it out .. thankyou once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting property 'secretRequired' to 'false' did not find a matching property ( This has been depreciated)
ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-1] StackTrace ( protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol")